# Packaging python resources (Manifest.in vs package_data vs data_files)

Tags: python, resources, setuptools, python-importlib

It seems that non-python resources are included in python distribution packages one of 4 ways:

1. Manifest.in file (I'm not sure when this is preferred over package_data or data_files)
2. package_data in `setup.py` (for including resources *within* python import packages)
3. data_files in `setup.py` (for including resources *outside* python import packages)
4. something called `setuptools-scm` (which I believe uses your version control system to find resources instead of manifest.in or something)

- **Which of these are accessible from `importlib.resources`?**
  (It is my understanding that `importlib.resources` is the preferred way to access such resources.) If any of these are not accessible via `importlib.resources`, then how could/should one access such resources?
- Other people online have been scolded for the suggestion of using `__file__` to find the path to a resource because installed wheel distributions may be stored as zip files and therefore there won't even be a proper path to your resources. **When are wheels extracted into site-packages and when do they remain zipped?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of (1)-(3) will put files into your package (don't know about (4)).
At runtime, `importlib.resources` will then be able to access any data in your package.
At least with Python 3.9, which can access resources in subdirectories.
Before, you had to make each subdirectory a package by adding a `__init__`.

As for why not use `__file__`: Pythons import system has some weird ways to resolve packages. For example it can look them up in a zip file if you use Zipapp.
You may even have a custom loader for a package you are asked to load some resources from.
Who knows where those resources are located? Ans: importlib.resources.

Afaik, wheels are not a contender as those are unpacked.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I think I was misunderstanding...I thought that, when installed, wheels (which are zip files) remained zipped in site-packages. What I'm understanding from your answer, however, is that wheels are extracted and don't remain zipped, so using `__file__` is pretty much only a problem if you're using Zipapp or if your package will be imported using a custom loader. Is this correct?

Comment: Wheels are unpacked. Just do a `pip -v install wheel` (which happens do be a wheel).
You will get a message saying _Created temporary directory: C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-udmgqd5b_

Comment: So is it correct to say that the only problems with using `__file__` which you are aware of are Zipapp and custom loaders?

Comment: As far as I am aware of. But with Ziapapp also include frozen modules (those *.pyd files). If you only want to read resources from modules you provide via source or wheel distros, then you are probably save.
But also note that setting `__file__`  by the import system is **optional** as per specification, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__